# Can't see console output from IronPython instance embedded in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ironpython

I have some IronPython code I'm running in an AppDomain in C#, and I want to see the console output from the IronPython code. It's not appearing in the Output window in Visual Studio when I debug, or in the `stdout.txt` file I'm redirecting standard output to in my C# app. I also tried this, to no avail:

```
engine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(File.OpenWrite("stdout.python.txt"), Encoding.Unicode);
engine.Runtime.IO.SetErrorOutput(File.OpenWrite("stderr.python.txt"), Encoding.Unicode);
```

These files get created, but they're blank... how do I see the console output from my IronPython code?

Comment: For minimal examples this should "just work" (both wiring stdout and using a file). Could you give more details on what you are doing with the appdomain? Any chance that the appdomain dies before stuff is written/flushed?

Comment: I don't think the AppDomain is begin disposed of; it's set up in the static constructor of my ScriptEngine class and is reused for all my script calls.